# Airflow DataprocSubmitJobOperator - how to pass data between tasks using XCOMS or other alternate ways

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using DataprocSubmitJobOperator in Airflow and am trying to pass data between tasks.
Here is the dag:

```
with models.DAG(
        'Versa-kafka2mongo',
        # Continue to run DAG twice per day
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        #schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
        # schedule_interval='30 11 * * *',
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        ) as dag:

    # create_dataproc_cluster
    create_dataproc_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id="create_dataproc_cluster",
        cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
        region=REGION,
        cluster_config=CLUSTER_GENERATOR_CONFIG
    )

    run_dataproc_spark_getcutomers= DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
        task_id="run_dataproc_spark_getcutomers",
        job=PYSPARK_JOB_GETCUSTOMERS,
        location=REGION,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    )

    # alarmBlock
    run_dataproc_spark_alarmblock = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
        task_id="run_dataproc_spark_alarmblock",
        job=PYSPARK_JOB_ALARMBLOCK,
        location=REGION,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    )
    # # insights
    run_dataproc_spark_insights = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
        task_id="run_dataproc_spark_insights",
        job=PYSPARK_JOB_INSIGHTS,
        location=REGION,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    )
    # few other tasks 
    
    delete_dataproc_cluster = DataprocDeleteClusterOperator(
        task_id="delete_dataproc_cluster",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
        region=REGION,
        # trigger_rule="all_done"
        trigger_rule=trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )
    create_dataproc_cluster >> run_dataproc_spark_getcutomers >> [run_dataproc_spark_insights, run_dataproc_spark_alarmblock] >> delete_dataproc_cluster
```

run_dataproc_spark_getcutomers - uses Pyspark code to get data from Mongo, which is used by the subsequent tasks using DataprocSubmitJobOperator i.e. run_dataproc_spark_insights, run_dataproc_spark_alarmblock (and few other tasks not listed)

Objective is to pass the customer list to the tasks - run_dataproc_spark_insights, run_dataproc_spark_alarmblock.

How do i do that ?
I was trying to use XCOMS, but it is giving me error - pls see code below

code for task - run_dataproc_spark_getcutomers,
which corresponds to job=PYSPARK_JOB_GETCUSTOMERS
This uses DataprocSubmitJobOperator, as shown in the Dag

```
# read from kafka, put into mongo
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType, LongType, IntegerType
import configparser,sys

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()

print(" parser ", parser)
read_params = parser.read('params.cfg')
print(f" after reading params.cfg, {read_params} ")
mongoConnUri = parser.get('mongo', 'mongoConnUri') + "?retryWrites=true&w=majority"


def main(**kwargs):
    if kwargs is None:
        kwargs = sys.argv

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('kafka2mongo').getOrCreate()
    # spark.newSession
    cust_db = parser.get('mongo', 'customer_db')
    customer_collection = parser.get('mongo', 'customer_collection')

    print(f" cust_db : {cust_db}, customer_collection : {customer_collection}")

    dfm = spark.read \
        .format('mongo') \
        .option('database', cust_db) \
        .option('collection', customer_collection) \
        .option('uri', mongoConnUri) \
        .load()

    dfm.show(5, False)
    if dfm and dfm.count() > 0:

        dfm = dfm.select('customerName')
        custList = dfm.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
        kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='customers',value=custList)

if __name__=="__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/d6f5c321-fd5c-4287-9a6d-f2a05db40596/getcustomers.py", line 44, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/d6f5c321-fd5c-4287-9a6d-f2a05db40596/getcustomers.py", line 41, in main
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='customers',value=custList)
KeyError: 'ti'
```

Any inputs on how to debug/fix this ?
tia!

Comment: What is `main()` ? How do you expect airflow to execute this function? Your code doesn't show how the function is triggered from Airflow. Is it PythonOperator? Please show the full code.

Comment: @EladKalif  - i've updated the description, the entire code is using DataprocSubmitJobOperator operator .. hope that clarifies

Comment: @EladKalif - the main() is called when Airflow runs the job -  run_dataproc_spark_getcutomers .. this gets the customers from Mongo, and needs to be used in the subsequent tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can save the output of dataproc in google cloud storage and retrieve it from there:

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-job-output#cloud-storage

Comment: yes, that can be done .. however, was checking if we can use XCOMS to pass data between tasks in the dag, when i'm using DataprocSubmitJobOperator. The feedback i got from the community is - this is not possible with DataprocSubmitJobOperator, though can be done with Python operator

Comment: Look at the definition of the operator and if you can't find it, it can't be done. But if you want to write your own operator that will a) submit Job b) wait for the job to complete c) retrireve the results d) push it to Xcom, this is entirely possible and it is actually encouraged for you to write custom operators in Airflow if those provided by community are not enough. You can even write a @task decorated method and use Dataproc hooks to achieve it.